# Node.js как разделить массив на несколько частей по параметру

Tags: массивы, node.js

Доброго времени суток!

Имею массив где в каждом элементе есть параметр category который повторяется у нескольких элементов. Как более просто разделить один массив на несколько ( в зависимости сколько в массиве разных групп ) по параметру category ?

```js
[
  { 
    id: 1,
    category: 'main'
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    category: 'main'
  },
  { 
    id: 3,
    category: 'system'
  },
  { 
    id: 3,
    category: 'social'
  },
]
```

Пример массива выше, нужно получить из него 3 массива с параметрами main, system и social. Буду благодарен за помощь. Возможно, есть готовые пакеты для разделения массивов таким образом.

Comment: На самом деле, задача элементарная, смущает только ваше условие "нужно получить из него 3 массива". Вам нужно именно три отдельных массива, присвоенных разным переменным или же допустим объект, типа такого `{"main":[/* ... */],"system":[/* ... */],"social":[/* ... */]}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё довольно просто, можно сделать например так:

**UPD** теперь 3 переменные у которых `map` будет работать

**UPD2** еще дополнил ответ

```js
const arr = [
  { 
    id: 1,
    category: 'main'
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    category: 'main'
  },
  { 
    id: 3,
    category: 'system'
  },
  { 
    id: 3,
    category: 'social'
  },
];

const result = arr.reduce((res, item) => {
  if (res.hasOwnProperty(item.category)) res[item.category].push(item);
  else res[item.category] = [item];
  return res;
}, {});

const categories = Object.keys(result)
categories.map(key => {
  result[key].map(item => console.log(key, item))
});
```

Comment: Только рекомендовал бы делать проверку в `if` с помощью `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @Deonis ну по сути, в данном коде разницы нет, так как `undefined` приравняется к false, а то что ключ примет значение `false` с сервера маловероятно, но ответ дополнил)

Comment: С этими данными не важно, но лучше перестраховаться. )) И дело тут больше в возможных значениях свойств... Например, замените значения `main` на `constructor` и результат будет неприглядный.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Теперь проблема в том что полученный массив result не получается перебрать с помощью map

Comment: @АртурФранк понятное дело, так как эт оне массив а объект с массивами! Если нужно разделить на 3 массива данный объект и каждый перебрать, то сейчас дополню ответ. Вам просто нужно раъединить объект на 3 переменные.

Comment: @АртурФранк Дополнил. Или просто можете например так вызвать `result.main.map(...)`

Comment: если я не знаю заранее количество и тип категории есть возможность перебрать?

```res.map(g => {
    g.map(i => {
        console.log(i)
    })
})```

Задача вообщем состоит в том чтоб перебрать ответ от сервера и сгенерировать меню на сайте. В теле ``res.map(g => {})`` создается ul элемент а в ``g.map(i => {})`` создается сам пункт меню li

Comment: @АртурФранк всегда есть возможность) Дополнил ответ ещё раз

Comment: Да, теперь именно так как планировалось =) Благодарю за уделенное время и помощь!

Comment: а разве main не должен иметь такой вид `"main":{....}` ?